# Build Action = None vs Copy to Output Directory = Do Not Copy

Tags: visual-studio

These two settings seem to be doing the same thing. Build Action = None and Copy to Output Directory = Do Not Copy.

What are the scenarios where:

- Build Action is None, but Copy to Output Directory is something else?
- Copy to Output Directory is Do Not Copy, but Build Action is something else?

Comment: You might want to use this for files that are temporarily disabled or, say, design notes that you want easy accessible from the Solution Explorer window.   If you need files for testing your app then one of the copy selections is appropriate.  Files that need to present on the user's machine ought to be marked as Action = Content so that an installer will know that they need to be deployed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output directory is normally the `bin` folder, so you would have a file being copied to the output directory for example if you have a library (.dll file) added somewhere else in the project and you need it to be copied to the `bin` folder.

Most files in a project has a build action that is different from None, but Copy to Output Directory set to Do Not Copy as they shouldn't be in the `bin` folder. For example a class (.cs file) has Build Action = Compile, and a view (.aspx file) has Build Action = Content.

Comment: Is it correct to assume then that if a file's Build Action is set to None, then the Copy to Output Directory value doesn't matter anymore?

Comment: @JonasArcangel: No, you would use Build Action = None if you have a file that would be copied to the `bin` folder, as you wouldn't usually want it included in the publish at the original place.

Comment: @Guffa but keeping build action none is copying file on original place as well.